# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel Not Loading

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having problems with Twitter Bootstrap carousel.

The javascript doesnt seem to load. It works fine on my local dev but does not when I push it to server.

```
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/script.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.carousel').carousel({
      interval: 6000,
      pause: "hover"
    });

      $(".carousel-inner > .item:first").addClass('active');



    $("#nav select").change(function() { window.location = $(this).find("option:selected").val(); });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a link to your site on the server?

Comment: Check the console logs on your browser, there might be some error logs related to some incorrect links.

Comment: Are you uploading your assests/js folder? any 404 errors?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to set `active class` on the first item **before** loading the carousel. Otherwise, it will fail.

Comment: Thanks for this i am a bit of a newbie when it come to JS. I have tried both mentioned and it now works many thanks!

Answer (score 5):

switch the sequence of js files

like this

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
```

intsead of

```
<script src="assets/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for this i am a bit of a newbie when it come to JS. I have tried both mentioned and it now works many thanks!